# GraphQL: prevent empty array as input

Tags: apollo, graphql-js

I'm learning GraphQL now and I faced a problem that I am unable to resolve.

i have defined type in schema as

input School {
    name: String!
    exams: [subject!]!
}
input subject {
    name: String!
    mark: Number!
}

But while running the server.
I give data as
"data":
{
"name":"varun",
"exams":[],
}

Server does not throw any validation error.
Please suggest me solution.
Is there any possible way to get validation error on passing exams as empty array.

I have tried alternate methods, but nothing works on schema level. I have to put a check explicitly to check exam field should not be an empty array.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

GraphQL cannot validate the length of a list. You need to include this validation logic as part of your resolver.